# Shoper - Displaying of variants in the product list

Tags: php, html, smarty

I want to display the available variants in the product list so that when I click on a variant, the main picture changes with a preview of what the variant looks like. I also want only the first 5 variants to be displayed, and the rest to be available only after entering the product.

Currently I have made such a code, but I am not so familiar with it that I can identify the mistakes I made.

At the moment, the first 5 variants are displayed to me, but for some reason, for products the same variants are displayed and it is impossible to click on them about the preview in the picture above not to mention

I created such code and placed it in the file tableofproducts.tpl

```
<div class="option_{$option.type|escape}{if 1 == $option.stock} option_truestock{/if}{if 1 == $option.required} option_required{/if}">
  <div class="variant-images">
    {foreach from=$option.values item=value name=variant_loop}
      {if $smarty.foreach.variant_loop.index gt 5}
        {break}
      {/if}
      <a class="option-image" title="{$value.name|escape}" data-value="{$value.id|escape}" style="background-color:{$value.color|escape};">
        <img src="{$value.image_path|escape}" width="7" height="7" alt=""/>
      </a>
    {/foreach}
  </div>
  <select id="option_{$option.id|escape}" name="option_{$option.id|escape}" style="display:none;">
    <option value="" title="">{translate key='choose'}</option>
    {foreach from=$option.values item=value}
      <option value="{$value.id|escape}" title="{$value.color|escape}" {if 1 == $option.stock}{productOptionValueStocksUnavailable product=$product->getIdentifier() optionValue=$value.id}data-unavailable{/productOptionValueStocksUnavailable}{/if}>{$value.name|escape}</option>
    {/foreach}
  </select>
</div>
```